# Ruby function context vs blocks

Tags: ruby, activeadmin

I'm trying to figure the following:
Used with active admin ui builder.

why this works

```
def edit_action
    column "" do |resource|
        links = ''.html_safe
        links += link_to I18n.t('active_admin.edit'), edit_resource_path(resource), :class => "member_link edit_link", :target => '_blank'
        links
    end
end
index do
    edit_action
end
```

while this doesn't

```
edit_action = Proc.new{
    column "" do |resource|
        links = ''.html_safe
        links += link_to I18n.t('active_admin.edit'), edit_resource_path(resource), :class => "member_link edit_link", :target => '_blank'
        links
    end
}
index do
    edit_action.call
end
```

The error that I'm getting is that the object Model (for example) does not have the method 'column'

Comment: Can you paste the error for your not-working example ? What's not working exactly ?

Comment: `edit_action.call` expects that whatever `edit_action` returns is an `Proc` (or equivalent) - is that the case in your case?

Comment: I didn't understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it's a scoping issue: `def edit_action` introduces a new environment, while `Proc.new` inherits the environment from the parent. In the first case, `column` is recognised because `ActiveAdmin` provides it for the `index` actions. In the second case, the scope where the Proc is defined doesn't know anything about any `column` method, so you get the error you've mentioned.

If you move the definition `edit_action = Proc.new{...` inside the `index do...` block, it should work again.